# JavaFX webview scrollbar draw not cleared

Tags: webview, javafx, scrollbar, fxml

I have an AnchorPane which contains a WebView that contains some content and a scrollbar. The WebView is loaded from an FXML file, and the content is plain html (and some css for styling of course).

Everything works fine, except when I want to scroll or resize the window. Then this happens (after some scrolling and resizing):

[image: Glitched scrollbar]
.

It looks like the scrollbar is redrawn but not cleared. Same goes for the horizontal scrollbar. I have another pane which also has a scrollbar (not a webview though) and that works fine.

The Java code for the HelpPane (which extends AnchorPane) is very simple:

```
public HelpPane() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/fxml/HelpPane.fxml"));
    loader.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    loader.setController(this);

    try {
        Node ui = loader.load();
        getChildren().add(ui);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The FXML that creates the webview is also nothing special:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="apnHelpBody" styleClass="paneBody" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <children>
        <WebView fx:id="webFunctionDoc" focusTraversable="false" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I really have no idea what is causing this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the  java version and environment used?

Comment: I'm using the newest java version, 8u40

Comment: Log a [bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).  When you do so, ensure that you include all code and resources and a full environment description so that it is possible for somebody to reproduce your issue using only the information in the bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was quite straightforward:
The background of the page I was rendering was transparent, so it looks like the scrollbar is never cleared. Changing the background to white fixed it.